# Amps spent in the following design

Tags: cmos

I have a  question about potential current wastage.

I am looking at connecting the output of a low power 2 input XOR chip to a GPIO on a microcontroller. The input to the XOR chip will be connected to a switch delivering 3.3V from a button battery. The circuit below will produce the pulse.

So, my question which is perhaps a silly question, is this. In the following diagram

[image: XOR Gate with delay on one input]

I will be applying either 0V or 3.3 V to the input line through a switch. Once the XOR gate sends the pulse to the microcontroller,  will the XOR chip then dissipate the 3.3V to ground, as the switch is closed, through an internal set of resistors, or not?

i.e. when the switch is closed and 3.3V is applied, after the pulse is sent by the XOR gate, is there an appreciable ongoing current?

The reason I ask is that I have a 220mAh battery and the switch could be closed for quite some time. I need a solution that pulses the uC through the output of the XOR gate, but does not continue to appreciably drain the battery once the pulse is sent.

Any suggestions on the best low power 2 input XOR chip to consider, if this is a solution that will work, is gratefully received.

Thanks

SteadyD

Answer (score 1):

The solution you show unfortunately still needs a resistor pull-up at the switch to work, and will dissipate power when the button is pressed.

If you're willing to use two GPIOs, here's how you could do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHeyMBm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- In button un-pressed state, the GPIO_SCAN is low.
- On detecting a button press, bring GPIO_SCAN high.
- Pulse GPIO_SCAN low every so often and test if the button is still pressed.
- On detecting button release, keep GPIO_SCAN low.

This would use less power.

Remote controls work like this, though multiply the pushbuttons by the number of keys.

Comment: Thank you @hacktastical, I have solved it using a 1M oHm resistor between Vdd and the GPIO pin. No pulse but once the GPIO is taken to ground the uC registers the change and there is 3.3V dropping over a 1M Ohm resistor so the amperage whilst the switch is closed is very small.

Comment: Glad that works out but one thing to consider is noise pickup on the pin with such a high-value pull-up. When a finger comes close to the switch it will couple and give false triggering. 1M ohm by itself isn’t enough to overcome this. Adding a cap in parallel (100~1000pf) will help.

Comment: Thank you. I will put that in...